# Constant property can be modified during initialization? MODIFIED? What?

Tags: swift, initialization, constants

Quote from the Swift 3.0 office document of the [Chapter: Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

> For class instances, a constant property can be **modified** during initialization only by the class that introduces it. It cannot be modified by a subclass.

To my understanding the **modified** involves the action after the **definition**, aka the action after **declaring** and **assigning value**, aka re-assigning values, therefore I tried the following code.

```
class SurveryQuestion {
    let text: String
    var response: String?
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = "do you like music?"
        self.text = text //Got an error here
    }
    func ask(){
        print(text)
    }
}
```

And I got an error at line `self.text = text`. The compiler asked me to change the property `text`from constant to variable. Isn't it says that the constant property can be modified by the initializer of the class which originally introduced it?

**Question:**  Am I understand the word **modified** wrongly? Is it means the action after the **declaring** rather than the **definition** which would lead to the **modified** is meant to by passing a value to the constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the documentation is not clear enough. You can set a constant property only once during initializing. You also would not be able to set it during initialization if the property's value was defined inline. Here is example.

```
class SomeClass {

    let someProperty: String = "A"

    init() {

        self.someProperty = "" //ERROR: Immutable value "self.someProperty" may only be initialized once.
    }
}
```

The compile time error `//ERROR: Immutable value "self.someProperty" may only be initialized once.` actually explains it well.

Comment: I agree with you, no matter how, the constant can only be set once. Either by assigning a default value in defining or by an initializer. Just this **Modified** script confuse me a lot.

Comment: The documentation tries to emphasize that only the class that introduced the constant can set it and not subclasses. Other part of the documentation says that "Once a constant property is assigned a value, it can’t be further modified". I think you are right that the note can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and help.